# oracle 19c apex 19.1 openid connect configuration error ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle19c, oracle-apex-19.1

I have created a new application is APEX 19.1 by selecting `Access Control Enable role-based user authorization` feature. The default Authentication Schemes `Application Express Authentication` works just fine. But when I change it to OpenID Connect and run the app, I get the following error

```
- ora_sqlerrm: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1283
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 924
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 902
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1136
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1473
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 416
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_SOCIAL", line 79
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_SOCIAL", line 145
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_SOCIAL", line 244
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_NATIVE", line 485
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_NATIVE", line 1256
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2840
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION", line 1970
```

and this is the error backtrace

```
- error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1283
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 924
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 902
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1136
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1473
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 416
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_SOCIAL", line 79
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_SOCIAL", line 145
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_SOCIAL", line 244
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_NATIVE", line 485
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION_NATIVE", line 1256
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2840
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_AUTHENTICATION", line 1970
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW", line 4058
```

I have tried the following way to solve the error

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
        host => '*',
        ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect'),
                           principal_name => 'apex_db_user',
                           principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```

The statement does proceed but I get the same error.

Then I thought maybe because I am not using SSL. So I have changed the default.xml file and added the following entry

```
<entry key="security.verifySSL">false</entry>
```

I am new to APEX so probably I am missing something. Is the feature `Access Control Enable role-based user authorization` enough?

Comment: Hi, are you using Social Sign in as authentication method ??  To a specific Oauth2 provider ?? or one of your own organization ??

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I am using the social sign in as authentication scheme type and then under Authentication Provider I have selected OpenId Connect Provider and using our organisational single sign on that acts as a OpenId Connect Server

Answer (score 1):

This is a security topic in Oracle, all network privileges for schemas are closed by default.

With sys as sysdba account, execute the code below. Don't forget to change the schema name and domain.

```
-- Execute as sysdba
DECLARE
  l_acl       VARCHAR2(100) := 'aclname.xml';
  l_desc      VARCHAR2(100) := 'description';
  l_principal VARCHAR2(30)  := 'APEX_SCHEMANAME'; -- UPPERCASE if applies
  l_host      VARCHAR2(100) := 'yourdomain.com'; --hostname to reach
BEGIN

  -- Connection rights
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(l_acl, l_desc, l_principal, TRUE, 'connect');
 
  -- DNS resolution privilege
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege(l_acl, l_principal, TRUE, 'resolve');
 
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(l_acl, l_host);
 
  COMMIT;
END;
```

You can know the schema name executing next query.

```
    SELECT TABLE_OWNER FROM all_synonyms
WHERE SYNONYM_NAME = 'WWV_FLOW' and OWNER = 'PUBLIC'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Enrique for your answer. I have sucessfully executed that code but I am still getting the same error. I suspect I have too many acl xml file. It should be related to the network because I didn't see any logs in the sso